# Visual Studio 2013 Publish Error - MSB3231 Unable to remove directory

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

In Visual Studio 2013 I am attempting to File Publish my website project to a remote web server.  I am getting the following error:

> C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets(720,5):
>   Error MSB3231: Unable to remove directory
>   "obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir". Access to the path
>   'AdditionalPhotos.aspx' is denied.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, with no luck.  Restarting VS did not help.  I checked the permissions on the directory and file referenced in the error and Windows Explorer would not let me see the file and folder permissions (You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings.)  The project is stored on a network drive, and I am administrator of that drive, so I'm not sure why I can't see permissions there.

Any ideas as to how to get around this issue?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you find the solution for that?

Comment: No, I never did.  My best guess is that the project is on a network drive instead of a local drive and VS had a problem with that.  I was in a time crunch and wound up taking the whole project back to VS 2008 where I knew there was no problem.  I hope to try again in the future with a local project rather than one on the network.